# String Concatenation in VBA

Tags: vba, string-concatenation

**I've got this function:**

```
Function GetFullNameCSV() As String
   GetFullNameCSV = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", ".txt")
End Function
```

**If the code looked like this hard coded:**

```
Filename:= "C:\directory\filename.txt"
```

**I could just replace it with this and get the same result:**

```
Filename:= GetFullNameCSV()
```

**Problem is it appears in the case of this string:**

```
Connection:= "TEXT;C:\directory\filename.txt"
```

**I need to use string concatenation, guessing something like this:**

```
Connection:= "\"TEXT;+GetFullNameCSV()+\""
```

**What the code I need to use?** Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all the sections are always delimited with a `;`, just split the string into it's parts and then do your changes and then join it together again.

So with your sample I think it would be something like (please note, written from memory, so might not be completely correct):

```
Dim parts() as String
parts = Split(str, ";")

parts(2) = GetFullNameCSV() ' assuming that part 2 is the one you want to replace

str = Join(parts, ";")
```

Comment: +1 but... that might work, but it's not string concatenation it's a delimited string split, transform, and join. Meaning that to me, that the code is taking something simple and making it complex. Meaning I just want to know how to do string concatenation in VBA. Feel free to leave your suggested approach, but I really need/want the way to do string concatenation.

Comment: @blunders: Well, I might have misunderstood your question, if you're just talking about concatenating strings together, all you need is the `&` operator, so it would be `"TEXT;" & strTemp`. However, if I have understood your question correctly, then I'd argue that my code is actually very easy for what it does, because under the hood it might do a lot of things, but that's all done by VBA so you don't have to worry about the details.

Comment: +1 Thanks, someone else posted that as well and then deleted it before I could ask this... Seems like to me "TEXT;" & strTemp would output "TEXT;"C:\directory\filename.txt when what I need is "TEXT;C:\directory\filename.txt" -- again, thanks!

Comment: So, it works -- which is odd, don't have time to think about it. Thanks for giving me the answer I needed. Cheers!

Comment: @blunders: The double quotes ("") are String *delimiters*, which means they get stripped to find the string within.To get the output you said you expected you'd need `"""TEXT;""" & strTemp`. The first quote opens the string, the second escapes the third to make it a literal (then escape, literal, closing after).